# OpenAL-Soft invalid enum error AL_FORMAT_STEREO_FLOAT32

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I'm trying to play wav file that has a 32bit bit per sample format. When I try and generate an OpenAL databuffer and give it AL_FORMAT_STEREO_FLOAT32 as a parameter for the format type, I get an OpenAL error code 40962 which I believe means invalid enum.

Why is that happening?

Here is how I generate the buffer in OpenAL.

```
alBufferData(buffer, AL_FORMAT_STEREO_FLOAT32, fWavDataIn, wavHeader.subChunk2Size, wavHeader.sampleRate);
```

8 and 16 bits per sample works just fine with AL_FORMAT_STEREO16 and AL_FORMAT_STEREO8. But AL_FORMAT_STEREO_FLOAT32 doesn't work. Why?

Comment: There are a few things missing from your post. First, what exactly is it you want to know (a clearly formulated question). Without that we can only guess what you want. Next we absolutely must know which efforts you already went, to, meaning, we absolutely have to see source code that accurately reproduces the problem in a concise manner. A so called MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry about that. I edited my post. I'm trying to understand why openal won't generate a buffer with a 32bit per sample. 8 and 16 works just fine. not 32 though.

Comment: Where you found that format? It seems that it's not defined in `al.h`.

Comment: I'm using OpenAL-Soft ext file. It seems that I might need to use  "AL_STEREO32F_SOFT" instead. But that still does not work. https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/blob/master/include/AL/alext.h

Comment: You can view the header file /usr/include/AL/al.h   to see it only mentions 8 and 16 bit formats

Answer (score 1):

AL_FORMAT_STEREO_FLOAT32 is not a native feature of OpenAL. You should check for "AL EXT Float32" in the alGetString( AL_EXTENSIONS ) before using floats.